# Concatenate custom data attributes inside attr() - error in IE 11: SCRIPT1028

Tags: jquery, concatenation, attr, skrollr

Anyone can help me?

I'm setting several custom data attributes (for skrollr), everything works fine, but in IE appears this error in the third line:
**SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number**

There is another way to concatenate the string and the variable **["data-" + h_window]** inside a attr()

```
  $(".line").attr({
    "data-0":  "height:70px; visibility:visible;",
    ["data-" + h_window]: "height:0px; visibility:hidden;"
  });
```

This error happens for every line similar to the third.
[block of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3o0k.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using brackets? `[]` are for arrays, but the `attr()` method expects a string or a number, so just delete those brackets. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Zeke , if I don't use it gives me this error even in Firefox **SyntaxError: missing : after property id**.  In IE **SCRIPT1003: Expeted':'**

Comment: Ok, then tell me what is `["data-" + h_window]` supposed to be. Also, what elements have the `line` class? It's obvious you're setting custom attributes, but I'm trying to figure out if this is the best way to do it. I was working just on the error output you got, but maybe there's more to it or IE just doesn't support something...

Comment: If I delete the first of this attr() https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3o0k.png  gives me an error in the next line that have brackets. So I think is not element `.line` because it gives me an error in the next one. 
I don't know if you know Skrollr.js but this allows to change the css proprieties along the scroll, that's why I'm using

Comment: @Zeke The correct way to do this with skrollr is like this `<div data-_foobar="left:0%;"></div>`. But since I started doing it this way and I already have several lines to do the animations, I was trying to correct it. But if there is no way to concatenate the string and variable, I'll redo it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, I know, but the error does say it's a data type problem, therefore it's expecting a string or a number but that's not what it's getting parsed. Have you tried using `h_window.toString()`? Maybe that will help.

Comment: I mean, I never use IE but its console might need to make sure it's a string, unlike other browsers. This is stupid to me but I've found myself in similar situations and that solves it.

Comment: I tried now but it gives me the same error, thanks anyway. I will do it the way plugin advises